# How can I prevent a turbo destroy link from being clicked twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, stimulusjs

Given a `link_to` with a `turbo_method: :destroy` how I can prevent it from being quickly double clicked?

```rb
<%= link_to "X", items_path(@item), data: {turbo_frame: "frame",turbo_method: :delete} %>
```

Assume a controller action that removes the item via Turbo.

I'd like to avoid calling the destroy action more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your destroy method redirects to another page.  Have you tried to set the status of that redirect to :see_other (303)?

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45393

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent the double click you can use confirmation dialog functionality using stimulus. Unfortunately turbo has some issues, that @Correlator mentioned in his answer, and there is a workaround to those issues by changing the response to 303 code.

Here is a video tutorial that shows how to setup that confirmation and how to workaround that issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1GAYLQvtBU